# Query a table that has spaces in its name

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, tablename

I have a situation, I have a Access table named *Gas Flow Rates* that I want to add records. When I try to run my insert query for a similar table *Common Station*, I get the following error:

> "error hy000: syntax error, in query incomplete query clause"

Code is:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

class MainClass
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = "Dsn=Gas_meter";
    string sqlins = "";
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

    OdbcCommand cmdnon = new OdbcCommand(sqlins, conn);
    conn.Open();

    try
    {
       cmdnon.CommandText = "INSERT INTO 'Common station' ( S1Flow, S2Flow, S3Flow, S4Flow) VALUES (9999,999, 999, 999)";
        //Once the above line works replace it with cmdnon.CommandText= "INSERT INTO Gas Flow Rates ( S1Flow, S2Flow, S3Flow, S4Flow) VALUES (9999,999, 999, 999)"
        int rowsAffected = cmdnon.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(rowsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
}
```

How do I overcome that error?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Surround the spaced out item with square brackets:

```
[Common station]
```

Then slap the guy who designed the database.

Comment: Thanks, I absolutely would if he didn't live Arizona. I think that I will send him a clip of the Chappelle show Rick James skit where Rick James tell him what did the five fingers say to the face joke. LMBO

Comment: I have an issue with a guy using keywords as column names. Same solution (i.e. [] - and perhaps the slap?). There are reasons we don't do this (does the word maintainability mean anything?).

Comment: Not really, it doesn't hold any great importance that cant be derived from either Gas_Flow_Rates or GasFlowRates. This is just the way that he created the table as far as I know.

Comment: I laughed really hard at this.

Answer (score 7):

`SELECT * FROM [My Crazy Table With Spaces and Other Chars!]`

Use brackets to "quote" table and field names.

Answer (score 4):

```
  cmdnon.CommandText = "INSERT INTO '[Common station]' ( S1Flow, S2Flow, S3Flow, S4Flow) VALUES (9999,999, 999, 999)";
    //Once the above line works replace it with cmdnon.CommandText= "INSERT INTO Gas Flow Rates ( S1Flow, S2Flow, S3Flow, S4Flow) VALUES (9999,999, 999, 999)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party I know, but have just solved my own issue here...
Playing in access 2007 using ODBC connection to an SQL Db.

Table name is Employee_Appointment Extra Detail Custom
Syntax to select is as follows
SQlRecordSet.Open "Select * from [Employee].[Appointment Extra Detail Custom]", Conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Hope this saves someone else a few hours of playing!