# c# query with space in Sqlt table

Tags: c#

Is there someone who can help me?

I have to do a query in a database which was created by someone else. The problem I encounter is that the name of the table contains three spaces.

Example of the query: "SELECT * FROM `Item Journal Line`".

It does not work anyway, I've tried by surrounding the tablename with `[]`, `` `, ´´, '', ``´ but nothing is working.

Any suggestion on how to address this table in my query? I've searched on the web but I did not find anything which could help me. I'm working in c# with SharpDevelop.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Could you provide a bit of code?

Comment: I don't see double-quotes listed:  `String sqlString = @"SELECT * FROM ""Item Journal Line""";`

Comment: @DonBoitnott -> it does not work too but thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498251/query-a-table-that-has-spaces-in-its-name-ms-access-c-sharp-vs2008 (If using Access)

Comment: Congrats to the developer create table with such name. When you say does not working what do you mean. Are you getting exception or does not return values?

Comment: @Serge what do you want to say by DBMS?  the code seems to be good because when i try with an other table without space in the name i do not have any problem...

Comment: Dave Rook i think your r abslutely right. It work and on sql

Comment: @kostas ch -> i'm in accord with you... else i have an exception

Comment: what r u using SQLserver or mysql ?

Comment: @pidel, he means what database management system are you using? MS SQL Server? MySql? Access?

Comment: @Dave Rook & kostas ch. -> it is a SQL Server Database

Comment: I have just create a table with the name <test test test> and in my select command select dd from [test test test] it plays very well.

Comment: Provide please the code you are running

Comment: i recommend that you use entity framework.

Comment: @pidel If it's SQL server database, it should work with `SELECT * FROM [Item Journal Line]`. had you missed something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you table name is `test table`

In MSSQL (which i guess this is what you are using) run

```
select * from "test table"
```

To create this string in `C#` use [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx), and escape `"` with`\"`

```
string queryStr = "select * from  \"test table\" " ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The sanctioned way to access a Sql Server database table containing spaces or other reserved characters is through the use of square brackets. But you should not include the dbo part in that otherwise the search will fail because there is no table with `dbo` as first 3 characters.

```
string strConnection = "server=***;" + "database=***;" + "uid=***;" + "pwd=***;"; 
string query = "SELECT * FROM [Item Journal Line]";
using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
using(SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand(query, myConnection))
{ 
     myConnection.Open(); 
     SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader() 
}
```

However, if your really have tables with so weird names, consider to create a view with more easier names to work with

Answer (score 1):

In `Postgresql`

```
 String query= "select * from appsetup.""fsd sdfsd sdfds"""

pass this query in `command`
```

Answer (score 0):

Dave Rook said it in your comments.

The answer to the question you asked is over here:
[Query a table that has spaces in its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498251/query-a-table-that-has-spaces-in-its-name-ms-access-c-sharp-vs2008)

```
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * from [Item Journal Line]";
```

Did this solve your problem? Maybe someone added a space or something evil in the name of your table.

```
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * from [Item Journal Line /n]";
```

If this isn't solving your problem it could be something else besides what you have asked, can you post the error message or tell us if the problem is resolved?