# MS Access - Cascading 2nd Combobox Not Cascading

Tags: ms-access, combobox

On a form called `opportunity` I have a combobox called `cmbCompanyName` to select a company name from a table called `Company`.  This is the first part of my cascade.

The `cmbCompanyName` has three columns.

Col 0 is the CompanyID, which is hidden.
Col 1 is the CompanayName, which is populated to the form
Col 2 is the CompanyCity, which is populated using a different part of the form using the control `=[cmbCompanyName].[Column](2)`

All of this works correctly.

The second part of my cascade `cmbPoCLastName` looks at another table called `Contacts` and should take the CompanyName from `cmbCompanyName` to filter my choices.

`cmbPoCLastName` uses the following query

```
SELECT Contacts.Company, Contacts.[Last Name], Contacts.[First Name], Contacts.[E-mail Address], Contacts.[Business Phone]
FROM Contacts
WHERE (((Contacts.Company)=[Forms]![Opportunity]![cmbCompanyName]));
```

To support my cascasde, `cmbCompanyName` requeries `cmbPoCLastName` upon update.

```
Private Sub cmbCompanyName_AfterUpdate()

cmbPoCLastName.Requery

End Sub
```

All of this result in nothing showing up in the second part of my cascade.

I believe the issue is `cmbPoCLastName` is filtered by the hidden CompanyID.  I cannot figure out how to force this query to look at the company name vs. the ID number.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you saving company name into Contacts instead of company ID? Query object cannot see columns of combobox. If you want company name then have a textbox that pulls company name from combobox column then query object references textbox. If you don't use CompanyID as filter criteria then why bother having in combobox column?

Comment: Or use VBA to set combobox RowSource with SQL statement. Or eliminate ID column and company name is value of combobox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cascading combo boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645191/cascading-combo-boxes)

Comment: @June7, your comment about the `CompanyID` did the trick.  I've created a 1 to many relationship between `CompanyID` on both `Contacts` and  `Company`.    Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the first comment made by @June7, I reworked my tables to use `CompanyID` to related them to one another.  I had previously used `CompanyID` in some tables and `CompanyName` in others.